# How can I force TransactionScope to use the same connection across Database calls?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, try-catch, transactionscope

Good Morning All,

I have code similar to the following

```
try{
    using(var tx = new TransactionScope()){

        var Xupdated  = someDao.DoSomeUpdateQuery(); //this dao uses MS Data ApplicationBlock

        var Yupdated = someDao.DoSomeOtherUpdateQuery(); //this dao also uses MS Data ApplicationBlock

     if(Xupdated && Yupdated)
     {
        tx.Complete();
     }

    }
} catch(Exception ex){

   DoSomethingWithTheException();
}
```

The dao methods have code like this

```
 try{
 var db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
 var cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(someSP);
  var retVal = db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
 return (retVal > 0);
} catch (SqlException ex){
    CustomException custom = new CustomException(ex.Message, ex);
  throw custom;
```

}

The problem here is when 'Yupdated' returns false, I want 'DoSomeUpdateQuery()' to be rolled back. Unfortunately, 'DoSomeUpdateQuery()' changes are committed. How can i remedy this? I put a breakpoint in and tx.Complete() is never called. Does anyone know how I can get the appropriate desired behavior here? Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the appropriate behavior as long as the `DatabaseFactory` class, whatever it is, behaves in a cooperating manner. If the someDao calls seem to act independently, it could mean they are actively creating an inner scope with [TranscationScopeOption.Supress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscopeoption.aspx). Another issue could be if the `CreateDatabase` call internally caches some SqlConnection and does not relies on SqlClient connection pool, thus possibly by-passing the connection enrollment into the transaction.

As a side note, even when this works as desired, it will be mighty inefficient because you'll enroll two distinct connections into a distributed-transaction and this will slow processing a *great* deal. A good data access layer accepts the Sqlconnection to use as a parameter so it can share it between calls, thus keeping the transaction scope *local* on the server.